# Umask on the command line

Tags: command-line, umask

Where can I go to set a `umask` for any new users I create through the command line? I think it's through the `/etc/.profile` but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

The file you search is `/etc/login.defs`. There is a variable set. See:

```
UMASK           022
```

The values in this file are used by the utillities `useradd`, `userdel` and `usermod`.